# Rails render auth_token to API response header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, authentication

I have custom JSON authentication API (without devise, etc). How do I render `@user.authentication_token` to response header instead of body?

in **`sessions_controller.rb`**

```
  def create

    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
      @user.sign_in_count += 1
      @user.save!

      render  status: 200,
              json: { success: true,
                      info: "Logged in sucessfully.",
                      data: { auth_token: @user.authentication_token } }
    else
      render  status: :unprocessable_entity,
              json: { success: false,
                      info: "Login failed." }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the response.header["auth_token"]

```
    def create

        if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
          @user.sign_in_count += 1
          @user.save!

          render  status: 200,
                  json: { success: true,
                          info: "Logged in sucessfully."}
                   response.headers["auth_token"] = @user.authentication_token

        else
          render  status: :unprocessable_entity,
                  json: { success: false,
                  info: "Login failed." }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you, it works only without comma after json block

Answer (score 4):

There is a `headers` object available in your controller action. So you can do the following:

```
headers['X-User-Token'] = @user.authentication_token
```